# How to correctly pin a HubTile to the start screen

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I would like to be able to pin a hubtile in my application to the start screen, so that the start screen tile has the same animation effects as my hubtile. WHen the user clicks on the pinned hubtile, he or she will be navigated to the correct page. I have followed this example http://igrali.com/2011/09/27/how-to-pin-a-hubtile-to-start-screen/ , but it does not work for me?

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tileList" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <toolkit:HubTile Title="{Binding Title}" Margin="3"
                                         Notification="{Binding Notification}"
                                         DisplayNotification="{Binding DisplayNotification}"
                                         Message="{Binding Message}"
                                         GroupTag="{Binding GroupTag}"
                                         Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
                                         Tap="hubTile_Tap">
                            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="menu">
                                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="pin to start" Tap="MenuItem_Tap"/>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </toolkit:HubTile>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateHubTiles();
    }

private void CreateHubTiles()
    {
        List<TileItem> tileItems = new List<TileItem>() 
        {
            new TileItem() { ImageUri = "/Images/shareStatusImage.jpg", Title = "status", /*Notification = "last shared link uri",*/ Message = Settings.statusMessage.Value, GroupTag = "TileGroup" },
            new TileItem() { ImageUri = "/Images/shareLinkImage.jpg", Title = "link", /*Notification = "last shared status message",*/ Message = "last shared link uri", GroupTag = "TileGroup" }, 
        };

        this.tileList.ItemsSource = tileItems;
    }

private void MenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        HubTile tap = sender as HubTile;

        CreateLiveTile(tap);
    }

    private void CreateLiveTile(HubTile hubtile)
    {
        //First create a new StandardTileData object from the hubtile to be pinned

        //NullReferenceException occurs here!!
        StandardTileData LiveTile = new StandardTileData
        {
            BackBackgroundImage = ((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)hubtile.Source).UriSource,
            Title = hubtile.Title,
            BackTitle = hubtile.Title,
            BackContent = hubtile.Message
        };    

        //Check to see if the tile already exists
        //If not, create it
        //If yes, display messagebox
        ShellTile Tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("DefaultTitle=" + LiveTile.Title));

        if (Tile == null)
        {
            try
            {
                ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?DefaultTitle=" + LiveTile.Title, UriKind.Relative), LiveTile);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This tile could not be pinned", "Warning", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This tile has already been pinned", "Notice", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        }
    }
```

I am stuck on this and how it could be changed so that it will work!? Also, does this actually place a hubtile on the start screen, or just use the hubtile data to create a secondary tile?

Comment: what exactly is failing? Your code looks fine

Comment: Theres a NullReferenceException when creating the `LiveTile` in the `CreateLiveTile()` method. as as for your answer below, im assuming u mean that it is currently impossible to pin a HubTile to the start screen and have the same effect? And if so, might you know of any way to animate a start screen tile, besides the normal front and back flip animation?

Comment: Sorry, but more animations are not supported in Windows Phone 7.5. What line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: On `StandardTileData LiveTile = new StandardTileData{ .. }` when I attempt to get the properties of hubtile such as Title and Message they are null. As far as I can tell, its because I'm attempting to get those properties in `MenuItem_Tap` event handler and pass it into the `CreateLiveTile(HubTile hubtile)` parameter which does not work. I still would like to create normal secondary tiles, and changed my implementation accordingly, but I am unsure of how to get the hubtile properties still? Can this be done in `MenuItem_Tap`, and if not, would you have a suggestion as to how?

Comment: I looked into somehow getting a reference to the specific hubtile where the contextmenu click occured, and get the hubtile properties that way, but I cannot find any resource or figure out how to do this?

Comment: AH, Yes. the tapped item is not a HubTile, but a MenuItem. I updated my answer and I would also recommend using the Click event rather than the Tapped event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to pin a hubtile in my application to the start screen, so that the start screen tile has the same animation effects as my hubtile

Live tiles for "normal" apps (not first party apps) are limited in what they can do. You can only provide a [front/back image, front/back text a back content, and a count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.standardtiledata%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). This is all that we have access to.

**UPDATE** Adding more info based on error being received
You can accomplish this by getting your TileItem

```
void MenuItem_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var tileItem = menuItem.DataContext as TileItem;
    CreateLiveTile(tileIte);
}
enter code here
private void CreateLiveTile(TileItem item)
{
    // use the TileItem, not HubTile.
}
```